# Downloading a PDF file with Spring results in corrupt file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have implemented a controller in Spring that writes the contents to a pdf file (via input stream) to the `ServletOutputStream`, however when comparing the contents of the existing file and the downloaded file it appears to be corrupt.

```
 public class DownloadFileController {

    @GetMapping(value = "v0/file")
    @ResponseBody
    public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response) {

      try (ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
          InputStream inputStream = getFile()) {

        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"example.pdf\"");
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);

      } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ...
      }
    }

    private static InputStream getFile() {
      return DownloadFileController.class.getResourceAsStream("/example.pdf");
    }
  }
```

The HTTP request is successful and responds with the contents of the PDF, however it is litered with: `�`

**Edit:**
The file won't always be PDF, it can also be images, word documents etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was me being an idiot and interpreting the binary response as text which resulted in unknown characters.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
```

to

```
response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set content-type to** `application/pdf` **for downloading .pdf files**.

You can use this `setContentType()` method to set the content-type and set the **Content-Disposition** in the response header using `addHeader()` method from `HttpServletResponse` class.

For example :

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=example.pdf");
```